# Sort() leads to Segmentation Fault

Tags: c++, string, stl

I have to implement a `shuffleString(string s,int d)` method where the first step involves getting the count of each character in the string and arranging them in the decreasing order of their count. I implemented the required functionality as follows:

```
 struct node{
    char ch;
    int ctr;
 };
 bool myfunc(const struct node x,const struct node y){
    return (x.ctr>=y.ctr?true:false);
 }
 string shuffleString(string s,int d){
     int i,j;
     int len=s.size();
     vector<struct node> counter(26);
     for(i=0;i<26;i++){
         counter[i].ch='a'+i;
         counter[i].ctr=0;
     }
     for(i=0;i<len;i++){
         counter[s[i]-'a'].ctr++;
     }
     sort(counter.begin(),counter.end(),myfunc);//From STL's algorithm
     /*
       Remaining Functionality
     */
  }
```

However, the code generates a `segmentation fault` when the `sort()` method is called. What is wrong with my code? Please help.

P.S. The string only contains lowercase ASCII characters.

Comment: What have you done to [debug your small program](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) so far?

Comment: Couldn't think of much...wrote a  print statement in the myfunc() method. The sort method seems to be running endlessly.

Comment: Moreover, when I removed the '=' in the statment 
'return (x.ctr>=y.ctr?true:false);' the program seemed to execute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

`bool myfunc(const struct node x,const struct node y){
    return (x.ctr>y.ctr) || (x.ctr == y.ctr && x.ch < y.ch);
 }`

EDITED:

1. you should handle the break tie case (separate `>` and `==` cases instead of `>=`)
2. Your algorithm will fail when input has any char other than `a-z` (even `A-Z`)

A small snippet is here:

```
struct node{
    char ch;
    int ctr;
};
bool myfunc(const struct node x,const struct node y){
    return (x.ctr>y.ctr) || (x.ctr == y.ctr && x.ch < y.ch);
}
void shuffleString(string s){
   int i,j;
   int len=s.size();
   vector<struct node> counter(26);
   for(i=0;i<26;i++){
      counter[i].ch='a'+i;
      counter[i].ctr=0;
   }
   for(i=0;i<len;i++){
      counter[s[i]-'a'].ctr++;
   }
   for(int i=0; i<26;i++) cout << counter[i].ch <<"," << counter[i].ctr  << endl;

   cout << endl << endl;

   sort(counter.begin(),counter.end(), myfunc);//From STL's algorithm

   for(int i=0; i<26;i++) cout << counter[i].ch <<"," << counter[i].ctr  << endl;

}

int main()
{
   shuffleString("hello");

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You likely have got memory corruption in the line: counter[s[i]-'a'].ctr++;

s[i]-'a' can be more than 25, what is out of the vector boundary.

Comment: Only lowercase ASCII characters in the string. Question edited.

Answer (score 0):

stl sort uses `operator<` by default - it expects the function you pass in to behave in the same way.

This means that if it calls the function on two identical values it should get false, but in your case it would get true. Because of this it will not correctly sort.

When you remove the = the function no longer has this issues since `operator>` is non reflexive like `operator <`

If you run with the debug c runtime STL will first assert that the passed in function is well formed.

Comment: Removing the '=' would however change the relative ordering??
Anyways...thanks..I got the error.